# Git pull a repository to local computer from a remote computer

Tags: linux, git, macos, ssh

I have setup an ssh connection on computer B and I am connecting to it properly via ssh. I want to execute a `git pull` command so that it would pull the repo to computer A instead of B. Is that too much of a hassle or maybe is there an alternative?

I basically need to copy whatever `git pull` pulled on computer B to my computer A. The only thing I have is just an ssh connection between the two and the repo is only reachable from computer B.

Comment: just copy the directory with scp

Comment: Is your actual goal to access B's remote repo (the repo B pulls from) on A? If yes, you should do that through an SSH tunnel. You don't need an intermediate repo on B. You can have A have direct access by tunneling through B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to run `git` commands over [double ssh tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28200914/7976758). The accepted answer there is a bit outdated, `ssh` currently can construct a tunnel without external commands like `netcat` or `socat`.

Configure in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server
   HostName git-server
   ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
```

This configures `ssh` to start a connection to the host `B` and opens a
tunnel over that connection to the host `git-server`. Run

```
git pull ssh://server/path/to/repository
```

Another possible solution is to use [`ext::` remote helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-ext). See the second answer at the linked question. Run

```
git pull "ext::ssh -t B ssh git-server %S '/path/to/repository'"
```

Comment: with ssh tunnel in mind, if my computer B gets its internet connection through a router which I cannot configurate in any way, can I still make a tunnel on computer B? Because if I try to establish a connection with ssh it is going to reach the router on port 22 first which would not know where to re-direct? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, you need an VPN (including a VPN over ssh) from B to a server V in the outside world. With this setup you can connect to B via V.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to use Git over an SSH tunnel so that computer A can access the repository REPO.git on computer C via computer B

1. On computer A, open the SSH tunnel:

   ssh -L3333:compC:22 compB
2. From a second console on computer A:

   git clone ssh://git@localhost:3333/REPO.git

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will answer your question, but if it's only for pulling, you can use the scp command after pulling on B:

```
scp <source> <destination>
```

It will copy as the cp command but through your ssh connection.

Comment: He don't want to copy stuff across using FTP. He wants to execute commands on computer B from A.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution,(and the most straightforward solution in my opinion) is to just :

- Connect to the remote machine via SSH
- Push the remote changes to a git branch
- Pull the changes from the remote branch from your local machine